# Using setAttribute on a selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and I cannot figure out how to use setAttribute on a selected option.

I have a select element in my html with id = employee (adding options using javascript)

```
<select name="employee" id="employee"></select>
```

Now, using javascript (or jquery) I am trying to add a "dept" attribute to the selected option dynamically.

However, below code doesn't work. What I am doing wrong here?

```
var sel = document.getElementById("employee");
var selected = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
selected.setAttribute("data-dept", Support);
```

I also tried:

```
$("#employee option:selected").setAttribute("data-dept", "Support");
```

That also didn't work. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
        <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
                function addOptions(selectId, list)
                {
                        var i, l, opt, sel, name;
                        sel=document.getElementById(selectId);
                        sel.options.length=0;
                        for(i=0, l=list.length; i < l; i++)
                        {
                                opt=document.createElement('option');
                                name=list[i].name;
                                opt.innerHTML=name;
                                opt.value=name;
                                opt.setAttribute("data-dept", list[i].dept);
                                sel.appendChild(opt);
                        }
                }

                function onEmplOptChange()
                {
                        var empDept=$("#employee option:selected").attr('data-dept');
                        $("#emp-dept").val(empDept);
                }

                function generateDept()
                {
                        return "Support";
                }

                function onGenBtnClk()
                {
                        var newDept=generateDept();
                        $("#employee option:selected").attr('data-dept', newDept);
                        $("#emp-dept").val(newDept);
                }

                function init()
                {
                        var list=[{"name": "Chris", "dept": "no department"}, {"name": "Boris", "dept": "no department"}];
                        addOptions("employee", list);
                        onEmplOptChange();
                        $("#employee").change(onEmplOptChange);
                        $("#gen-dept").click(onGenBtnClk);
                }

                init();
        });
</script>
<BODY class="textstyle">
        <div id="maindiv">
                <table>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="1" style="width: 80px; ">
                                        <select name="employee" id="employee"></select>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="1" style="width: 180px; ">
                                        <input type="text" id="emp-dept" disabled="true"/>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                <hr>
                <br> <input type="button" id="gen-dept" value="Generate Dept."/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work ..  :( ...Any other suggestions?

Comment: Here is a sample .. http://jsfiddle.net/u6pbzwg5/    .. Both 'Chris' and 'Boris'  are assigned to 'no department' at start. if I select 'Chris' and hit 'Generate Dept' button I see 'Support' in the text entry box as expected. However, if I change the employee to 'Boris' and change balk to 'Chris' , it is still set as 'no department'. I was expecting this to be 'Support' because of selected.setAttribute("data-dept", newDept);  command.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, you just need to run it on change event [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6pbzwg5/2/)

```
document.getElementById('employee').addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.selectedOptions[0].setAttribute('data-dept', 'Employee');
});
```